# Import combined column and line chart from CSV file

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I can successfully make a combined chart using the code from here:

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/
```

And I have also had success drawing simple charts from a CSV file following this example:

```
[2]: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing
```

What I'd like to do now is create a combined column and line chart using data from a CSV file. But I'm not sure how to get the two data types into the importing of a CSV file bit.

I've tried following the advice below and have got this far - I just cannot change one series to column and one to line:

```
$.get('CSV/career/career_jermy-m.csv', function(data) {
// Split the lines
var lines = data.split('\n');

// Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    var items = line.split(',');

    // header line containes categories
    if (lineNo == 0) {
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
        });
    }

    // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first 
    // position
    else {
        var series = {
            data: []
        };
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo == 0) {
                series.name = item;
            } else {
                series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
            }
        });

        options.series.push(series);

    }

});

// Create the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

});

Comment: You need to prepare your own custom parser, which do this. Manual with example how to parse data, you can find [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing). Obviosuly you need to edit that and adapt to your data / scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I am extremely novice at this and would appreciate an example of how this is done, if possible?

Comment: In the related link you have piece of code, which parse simple CSV, so you need to adapt to your expecattions.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure where to start. I don't really understand parsing data. Would it be possible to show me how you would make the example work, where John would be a column and Jane a line?

Categories,Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas
John,8,4,6,5
Jane,3,4,2,3